# cgminer no devices found

Tags: drivers, ati

When I run cgminer -n(version 3.12.2) I get:

```
 [2014-02-12 11:09:10] USB all: found 12 devices - listing known devices                    
 [2014-02-12 11:09:10] No known USB devices
```

when I run lcpci -v I do see my card:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Antilles [Radeon HD 6990] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 0b2a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fbac0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at ce00 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fba00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6900 Series]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6900 Series]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at fbafc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Antilles [Radeon HD 6990]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1b2a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fb9c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at be00 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fb900000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci

04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6900 Series]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6900 Series]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at fb9fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

fglrxinfo results are:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series  
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12337 Compatibility Profile Context 13.101



display: :0  screen: 1
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series  
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12337 Compatibility Profile Context 13.101
```

When trying to compile with ./autogen.sh (with or without --enable-opengl) I get

```
  OpenCL...............: NOT FOUND. GPU mining support DISABLED
configure: error: No mining configured in
```

Comment: OpenGL != OpenCL.You probably need to install some additional development packages to be able to enable OpenCL support.

Answer (score 1):

As dobey said I needed opencl, but the amd-sdk versions of opencl did not seem to work for me (I was probably installing them incorrectly). Most of the opencl installs uninstall fglrx and install nvidia drivers. This is one I found on a forum that got it to work:

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

Hope it helps somebody else!